# create a "for" loop to encrypt multiple files in python

Tags: python, encryption

Good morning. I am trying to create a "for" loop to search for every file with `.txt` in a single folder and encrypt them. I was able to successfully do it with a single file but I have been tasked to create a loop to repetitively encrypt multiple files in a single folder

**single_encrypt_file.py**

```
from cryptography.fernet import Fernet

file = open('key.key', 'rb')
key = file.read()
file.close()

for filename in os.listdir('testfolder'):

with open(filename, 'rb') as f:
    data = f.read()

fernet = Fernet(key)
encrypted = fernet.encrypt(data)

with open(filename, 'wb') as f:
    f.write(encrypted)
```

I am still a beginner in python and programming so it would be great if anyone have ideas on how I should modify my current code. Cheers!

Update: I have modified the code based on the given answer but I am getting an error saying "No such file or directory: testfile.txt" when the file clearly exists when I went to check.

Comment: the thing is that you encrypt them with the same encryption key and when decrypt all files has the same `value`...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First thing is to do is to find all the file names in the folder. To do that use `os.listdir()`.

Then you simply loop through the filenames:

```
import os
for filename in os.listdir('dirname'):
     ##do what you want
```

Be careful because you might want to check if the folder contains only the files you want to encrypt. Otherwise create an exception to ignore unwanted files

Comment: The 'dirname' is it the full path (something like 'Users/User/Documents/homework.txt') or a shorten directory name (something like '../Documents/')?

Comment: Depends on if you want to set an absolute path or a dynamic one.

Comment: When you use the with open() you can use the full path or the short path. I would advise the full path because the short path you are using only works because the python file is in the same folder as the files you want to encrypt

Comment: A new error came up saying "No such file or directory: testfile.txt" when I clearly went and check inside the folder itself and the file "testfile.txt" does exists. How do I fix this issue? Also updated the question to include what I have done so far in my code

Comment: Is your pyhton file in the folder? Also are there more than one files with the same name?

Comment: My python file is right outside the "testfolder" (Documents/single_encrypt_file.py) while my testfolder is at "Documents/testfolder/". Inside the folder I have testfile1.txt, testfile2.txt and testfile3.txt

Comment: Are you using the full paths in the with open()?

Comment: I was using 'testfolder' for the file path when i got that error. Then i switch to full file path like 'C:/Users/User/Documents/testfolder' and it also gave me the same error. The error happened at the code "with open(filename, 'rb') as f:"

Answer (score 0):

I managed to figure out the problem. turns out `os.listdir()` method gives you filenames without paths only and as I needed to open files in my current directory (testfolder) I needed to use another which is `os.path.join()`.

**single_encrypt_file.py**

```
for filename in os.listdir('testfolder'):

    testpath = os.path.join('testfolder', filename)
    #run encryption codes
```